# Does rolling forwards while in reverse gear damage my car?

Tags: clutch, opel, damage, manual-transmission, agila

In my 2003 Opel Agila, I rolled forward about 2m with the clutch in while still in reverse gear, and my transmission made a whining sort of noise.

The clutch was fully in at this point so I have not turned the engine backwards or anything.

Have I damaged anything by doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely not. There's no issue here. The engine/transmission were not coupled. There was no stress on the transmission. It just was running backwards from what it usually would. Really, it's no big deal.

Comment: +1. Allowing this to happen safely is one of the many things the clutch is for, It's just a more extreme case of engine and transmission revs not matching, which the clutch is used for all the time,